# Norm-null sequence of operators

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of bounded operators on $\ell_2$ such that $\lim_n\sup_i\Vert a_n\xi_i\Vert\to 0$ for every orthonormal system $(\xi_i)$ in $\ell_2$.

Is $(a_n)$ necessarily a norm-null sequence?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried?

Comment: Honestly I thought this would be known.  But I did not find anything.  Even in the case when each $a_n$ is a one-dimensional projection ...

Comment: At the moment even this question is not clear to me: Can a sequence of unit vectors $(\eta_n)$ satisfy the condition $\lim_n\sup_i|\langle \eta_n,\xi_i\rangle|\to 0$ for every orthonormal system $(\xi_i)$ of $\ell_2$?